# Running related apps in different servers

Tags: node.js, electron, desktop-application

I have `NodeJS` server for my `iPhone` and `Android` apps and I want to build an admin panel as desktop application using `Electron`.

From my research, I found out that `Electron` depends on its own version of node and it can't run on other server instance.

My questions are:

1) is it advisable to implement the admin panel using `Electron` knowing that it depends on its own version of NodeJS?

2) is there away to integrate my current `NodeJS` server for mobile apps to my Electron? because using two different servers will be costly when it comes to hosting them

3) what are other alternatives that enable me to implement cross-platform desktop application using my current mobile apps server?

**NOTE:** The admin panel server functionality are completely different from mobile apps.

Comment: Think of electron as a browser that can run node.  For example, a browser where you can access the file system and other systems that a typical browser would not have access to.  It would be perfectly fine to have one nodejs server that is accessed by iphone/android front-ends and from a distributed electron app that contains an admin panel front-end.  Or you can have the electron app access a different nodejs server.  That would work as well.

Comment: @user2263572 thanks, should I just add "app.on('ready', function() {" inside my mobile apps server and it would work? just to confirm because I am totally new to electron

Comment: You don't need to change anything in your node server other than adding additional endpoints for the admin functionality.  You can call your current nodejs server from your electron app.

Comment: @user2263572 oh I see, I believe I need to dig more into electron to get better idea of the from-end implementation. The idea I had that the from-end and the back-end are bundled in one like MeteorJS if you know of it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) is it advisable to implement the admin panel using Electron knowing that it depends on its own version of NodeJS?**

Yes, that is perfectly fine.  You can access your current node server directly from your electron app, or create a new node server that electron will access.

**2) is there away to integrate my current NodeJS server for mobile apps to my Electron? because using two different servers will be costly when it comes to hosting them**

You can run multiple nodejs servers on one machine (just use different ports when starting the servers).  This is one easy way to get around this issue, or you can just have a group of /admin endpoints that handle all admin related functionality. Think of electron has a front-end that can be distributed across various platforms and access any back-end you choose.

**3) what are other alternatives that enable me to implement cross-platform desktop application using my current mobile apps server?**

Electron / nwjs (node-webkit) are the only two that come to mind.  Although there are probably others.

**More Electron/nwjs details:**

Just think of these as browsers that allow you to write nodejs.  Therefore, within the browser you can access databases you ship with your app, or anything on the users file system.  You can also make requests from your app to already created nodejs servers.  Also, they allow you to easily package up your app for cross-platform distribution.

Comment: can you please show me an example of client side implementation of electron? and calling dummy URL? PLEASE!

Comment: Their tutorial is more detailed than anything i would write here.  https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/ .  Within index.html how do you normally make an ajax request to a server?